# How to set all values to NULL struct array within a struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Basically I have two structs and I want to make an array of A structs, and within each A struct I want an array of 50 B structs. So I assume that we will use double pointers.

```
struct A{
    char* a_word;
    struct B** b_list;
};

struct B{
   char* b_word;
   int b_value;
};
```

When call initialize function I initialize the structs like this. My goal is to set all the values to NULL when I allocate memory.

```
struct Word** initialize()
{
    int k;
    int i; 
    struct A** A_list = calloc(BUFFSIZE, sizeof(struct A*));
    for(k =0; k < BUFFSIZE; k++)
    {
     A_list[k] =  calloc (1, sizeof(struct A)); 
     A_list[k]-> b_list =  calloc(50, sizeof(struct B*));

        for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
           A_list[k]->b_list[i] =  calloc(1, sizeof(struct B)); 
        }

      }
return hashTable;
}
```

after initializing all these values I am able to do. . .

```
if(A[43]->a_word == NULL) //43 unallocated value
  {
    printf("This is null\n");
    //program prints this statement - good
    //program knows that this value is NULL
  }
```

But I also want . .

```
if(A_list[44]->b_list[0] == NULL)
{
   printf("This is also null");
   //This should be printed but nothing happens
}
```

For some reason not matter if I set the above if statement to `== NULL` or `!= NULL` the program outputs absolutely nothing from that if statement. What is going on in memory and how can I allocate everything correctly, and so the value is set to NULL as a default and so I can input a value?

EDIT: Also whenever try to do `A_list[value1]->b_list[value2] = strdup("string");` I get a segmentation error, this most likely stems from the same problem.

Comment: What do you think this is doing: `A_list[k]->b_list[i] =  calloc(1, sizeof(struct B));` ? Hint: it is **not** assigning `NULL` to that pointer. So testing for one later isn't going to do you much good. Now, what problem is this model *supposed* to be solving, a two-level hash table?

Comment: Yes I am making a two level hash table. In that calloc statement I am assuming that I am allocating space for a B struct.

Comment: ...which means checking `A_list[44]->b_list[0] == NULL` will evaluate as *false*, since you're initialization loop clearly populates it with an allocation address (assuming `calloc` doesn't fail, which should also be checked). Testing for non-null *and* fixing the output flush as alk's answer shows should get you output.

Comment: Your posted code won't compile. You don't have the declaration of `hashTable`. You should post the actual code that you are having problems with.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already by *[WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig)* in a comment to the question, this code

```
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
       A_list[k]->b_list[i] =  calloc(1, sizeof(struct B));
```

initialises the first 50 elements of `b_list` to point to valid memory, that is to be non `0`, assuming `calloc()` never fails. Being that optimistic you better test for those elements being `!= NULL`.

> ... if I set the above if statement to == NULL or != NULL the program outputs absolutely nothing

The code does not seem to flush `stdout` here:

```
if(A_list[44]->b_list[0] == NULL)  
{
   printf("This is also null");
```

Change this by adding a final `\n`:

```
if(A_list[44]->b_list[0] != NULL)  
{
   printf("This isn't null\n");
```

As `stdout` is line buffered by default, all content will be flushed if a new-line is detected.